# Dynamic tables/models using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, sequelize.js

This question is more of a theoretical one, since I have not started implementation yet.
The situation is as follows:

I have an application in which users can upload structured data (like Excel, CSV etc.).
Due to requirements, I want to store them in the database, ideally creating a new table on the fly with the table name set to the file name and columns based on the file itself.

This initialisation is still doable with sequelize, I think.
However, as sequelize relies on models, then I am stuck as I am not sure what type and how many columns there will be, thus creating the need for something off 'Dynamic model' or 'Generic model'.

I am not sure how to do this, and I cannot find anything related when searching. I would appreciate your 2 cents on this approach, and if there are other ideas I am very eager to hear them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you need to add code to map your `dynamic` columns into Sequelize column definition like:

```js
const columnDefinitions = [
{
  field: 'field_name_from_csv',
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true
},
{
  field: 'field_name2_from_csv',
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true
},
]
```

So you need to determine the data type of a certain column and create an appropriate column definition.

**Second**, you need to store all these mapping info in the special table(s) so you know what dynamic tables you have and how to register them in Sequelize.

Once you have a table name and column mappings you can register all tables as models in Sequelize:

```js
// here you need to convert an array of mappings into the object where field names should be keys and column definitions should be values.
const columnMappingsAsObject = ...
const tableName = 'dynamic_table_name'

const dynamicModel = sequelize.define(tableName, columnMappingsAsObject, {
  tableName
});
//  now you can use it to get records and so on:
const records = await dynamicModel.findAll({})
```